# Restart rspamd.service as non-root user

Tags: service, systemctl, www-data, rspamd

I have webpage with button, when user clicks on button, script `restart.sh` on server is executed. This script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl restart rspamd.service
```

After clicking on the button, `restart.sh` is executed, but rspamd.service is not restarted: *"Failed to restart rspamd.service: Access denied"* Because the script is executed by click on button on webpage, the real user who runs it on server is `www-data`. I tried to set suid bit to run script as root, but it's not working. How can I restart rspamd.service as `www-data` user?

Comment: well sudo could handle this. but remember that it is and will be always a wonderful security issue for ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with **sudo**. I tried it before, but I wrote it in wrong order. Edit **sudoers** with `visudo` and add this to end of file:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart rspamd.service
```

Then I can just run `sudo systemctl restart rspamd.service` and all goes well. Thanks.